# mobile safari setfocus on element

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ios5, setfocus

I'm developing a mobile app and will be using phonegap to create an iOS implementation.  I need to be able to setfocus on the next dataentry element (textbox).  iOS seems to block focus.  I've googled a lot for solutions and I'm not able to find anything that works on my iPhone.  Does anyone have a direction on setting focus on a form element and keep the keyboard open?